# Customizing colors on Dimple.JS charts

Tags: dimple.js

I would like to alter the colors of the bars on this [chart](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_horizontal), and change them from blue to orange.

Does anyone have a tip on how to alter/replace the CSS that modifies this?

Comment: Set the parent svg `fill="#80B1D3"` change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default colors directly:

```
chart.defaultColors = [
    new dimple.color("orange") // You can use #RGB here
];
```

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#defaultColors

The dimple.color constructor can also take stroke and/or opacity.  The elements in the array will be applied sequentially in a loop for each new series value which is encountered.

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.color

Or you can instruct the chart to not apply styles and define the formats entirely in css:

```
chart.noFormats = true
```

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#noFormats